# Finding a partial match between cells in different sheets

Tags: vba, excel

So in sheet "account", I have a column B, and from B2 to B990, I have identification numbers like 00AMSDF4 Corp, and in sheet "positions", from A2:A330 I have just the id, so "00AMSDF4."

I want to check if the ID appears in the column. I've tried Vlookup, which is difficult to do for partial matches (or I'm just bad), and I've tried several matches which show the value N/A.

Does anyone have any advice? Thank you so much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the MATCH function with the wildcard. For example, in cell B2 on sheet positions:

`=MATCH(A2 & "*", account!B$2:B$990,0)`